# pnpm unable to find global dir issue and working with docker

Tags: docker, pnpm

I am new to pnpm coming from npm. I asked this question in the discussion on [github](https://github.com/orgs/pnpm/discussions/6684) but didn't receive an ans for 2 weeks, so I am asking it here. I have a macos, zsh terminal, and nvm.
I ran into [unable to find global bin dir issue](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/4658) and ran the suggested `pnpm setup`. Opened a new terminal and ran `pnpm add -g pnpm` and got this message

```
➜  ~ pnpm add -g pnpm
Nothing to stop. No server is running for the store at /Users/me/Library/pnpm/store/v3
The location of the currently running pnpm differs from the location where pnpm will be installed
 Current pnpm location: /Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin
 Target location: /Users/me/Library/pnpm

Packages: +1
+
Packages are hard linked from the content-addressable store to the virtual store.
  Content-addressable store is at: /Users/me/Library/pnpm/store/v3
  Virtual store is at:             .pnpm

/Users/me/Library/pnpm/global/5:
+ pnpm 8.6.2

Progress: resolved 1, reused 0, downloaded 1, added 1, done
Done in 3.3s
```

Q1 > Will (line 3 "location differs warning") this cause any issues?!!

Q2 > Also how do I manage my docker containers. Perviously I had to do

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /codes
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run"]
CMD ["start"]
```

now would I have to install pnpm first and then `RUN pnpm add` and will the same issue of `unable to find global bin dir issue` arise?!